# How can I correctly and cleanly catch an error with gulp / gulp-watch

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

My gulp watch crashed after it catches an error like this:

```
Error: File not found with singular glob: C:\Windows\......\controller.js
```

I thought by using Gulp Plumber this problem could be solved. But it doesn't work. I can't catch this error. It seems that there is something that I am missing.

This is my script.js task:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (gulp, $) => () => {
    let allLibsJsApp = $.env.paths.app.js.map((path) => { return `build/${path}` });

    return $.merge2(
        gulp.src($.env.paths.libs.js, {base: '.'}) // $.env.paths.libs.js is the problem about the file missing
            .pipe($.plumber())
            .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
            .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.stripDebug()))
            .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.size({title: 'Annotate and StripDebug NodeModules Libs JS'})))
            .pipe($.if($.env.isDev, $.size({title: 'Annotate NodeModules Libs JS'})))
            .pipe($.if($.env.isDev, gulp.dest('build/libs'))),

        gulp.src(allLibsJsApp, {base: '.'})
            .pipe($.plumber())
            .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
            .pipe($.babel())
            .pipe($.if($.env.isProd,$.complexity({
                breakOnErrors: false,
                errorsOnly: false,
                cyclomatic: [5],
                halstead: [15],
                maintainability: 100,
                hideComplexFunctions: true,
            })))
            .pipe($.plumber())
            .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.stripDebug()))
            .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.size({title: 'Annotate, Babel and StripDebug App Libs JS'})))
            .pipe($.if($.env.idDev, $.size({title: 'Annotate, Babel App Libs JS'})))
            .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.replace('\'ngMockE2E\',','')))
            .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.replace('$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true)','$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false)')))
            .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.size({title: 'Uglify App libs JS'})))
            .pipe($.if($.env.isDev, gulp.dest('.')))
        )
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.concat('prod.js')))
        .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.uglify({mangle: {except: ['notify', 'complete', '_transferable_']}})))
        .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.size({title: 'Uglify All Libs JS'})))
        .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, $.rev()))
        .pipe($.if($.env.isProd, gulp.dest('build/libs')));
}
```

This is the process view to help you to understand.

```
> gulp build&&gulp serve

[13:08:46] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\print-cards-web\Gulpfile.js
[13:08:46] Starting 'build'...
[13:08:46] Starting 'clean'...
[13:08:46] Finished 'clean' after 30 ms
[13:08:46] Starting 'assets-html'...
[13:08:46] Starting 'assets-js'...
[13:08:46] Starting 'assets-json'...
[13:08:46] Starting 'assets-img'...
[13:08:49] copy json assets all files 1.37 kB
[13:08:49] Finished 'assets-json' after 2.95 s
[13:08:49] Plumber found unhandled error:
 SyntaxError in plugin 'gulp-babel'
Message:
    C:/Users/TEST/Desktop/print-cards-web/src/app/controllers/generalController.js: Unexpected token (207:2)
[13:08:49] copy html assets all files 2.72 MB
[13:08:49] Finished 'assets-html' after 3.09 s
[13:08:49] copy img assets all files 587.98 kB
[13:08:49] Finished 'assets-img' after 3.12 s
[13:08:49] copy js assets all files 342.92 kB
[13:08:49] Finished 'assets-js' after 3.17 s
[13:08:49] Starting 'sass'...
[13:08:49] Starting 'scripts'...
[13:08:50] 'scripts' errored after 902 ms
[13:08:50] Error: File not found with singular glob: C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\build\js\controllers\generalCon
    at Glob.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:39:11)
    at Glob.g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Glob.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Glob._finish (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\node_modules\glob\glob.js:172:8)
    at done (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\node_modules\glob\glob.js:159:12)
    at Glob._processSimple2 (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\node_modules\glob\glob.js:652:12)
    at C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\node_modules\glob\glob.js:640:10
    at Glob._stat2 (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\node_modules\glob\glob.js:736:12)
    at lstatcb_ (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\node_modules\glob\glob.js:728:12)
    at RES (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\node_modules\inflight\inflight.js:23:14)
    at f (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\print-cards-web\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
[13:08:50] 'build' errored after 4.11 s
[13:08:50] The following tasks did not complete: sass
[13:08:50] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

As you can see, i created a syntax error to test plumber in generalController.js. Plumber does intercept this error, but the script still continues and eventually crashes because the file was not built.
Plumber stopped the work and my file has not been moved in "build" folder.

What is the good process to manage all of this ?

Thank you in advance